# Emacs hangs when run through SSHing to my Ubuntu Box (13.10),

Tags: 13.10, ssh, emacs

Running Ubuntu 13.10, I cannot run emacs when sshing to my box

```
ssh -l username someipaddress
```

When I run emacs, it simply hangs.

I have also have recently installed dbus-x11 . Before installing dbus-x11, I would get a crash when trying to run emacs.

```
(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(emacs:3306): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

I have another ubuntu box (12.10) (vm though) running from a different provider.  However I have no issues running emacs.  In both cases I used apt-get to install emacs.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running the command you show, you are not exporting your X display details. You have two options:

1. Command line emacs:

   ```
   emacs -nw
   ```

   From `man emacs`:

   ```
         -nw, --no-window-system
                 Tell Emacs not to create a graphical frame.  If you  use
                 this switch when invoking Emacs from an xterm(1) window,
                 display is done in that window.
   ```
2. Forward your X server, this will allow you to run programs on the server that are shown on your local display. You can use either `-X`, or assuming this is a local, trusted network, `-Y`:

   ```
   ssh -Y username@someipaddress
   ```

   From `man ssh`:

   ```
    -X      Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host
            basis in a configuration file.
    -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not
            subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.
   ```